# Ignoring duplicate elements entered into array with a boolean function

Tags: c++, arrays

I can take in up to a 100 elements (nonnegative) into an array. I have to ignore repeat elements. I have my code written to basically take in every non negative element but it doesn't ignore repeats. I wrote a bool function ifExists:

```
bool ifExists(int array[], int size, int value)
{
   bool isThere = false;
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
      if (array[i] == value)
      {
         isThere = true;
      }
   }
   return isThere;
}
```

I call this function in the function that's taking user's input:

```
void getInput(int myArray[], int &numItem)
{
   int checkNum, number, count;

   cout << "Enter a number (- to quit): ";
   cin >> number;

   count = 0;
   while ((number > 0) && (count < 100))
   {
      if (!ifExists(myArray, numItems, number))
      {
      list[count] = number;
      count++;
      }
      if (count < 100) //&& !checkIfExists(list, numItems, number))
      {
         cout << "Enter a number (negative to quit): ";
         cin >> number;
      }
      else {
         cout << "no more space." << endl;
      }
   }
   numItems = count;
}
```

I think I wrote my ifExists wrong. The idea is that getInput should ignore repeated input from the user and just add unique values to my array. However, that's not what happens when I print the array. Can anyone help me in whether my ifExists is being called correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You don't set the value of numItems anywhere, except after the loop so your IfExists always gets the value of 0 and doesn't loop. Change it to count, which keeps track of how many numbers are in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your program contains n*n iterations where n is number of elements. This is not efficient at all specially for large data sets. Without doing that you can simply do something like this which only has 2 iterations.

1. iterate through the array one time and add those items in to a map. map structure (key = array value , value = count of the array value). when ever you find a entry in the map insert the count by 1.

2.Then iterate through the map 1 time and add all elements in the map which has value as 1 (single entry) in to your array which should not have duplicates.

Will share a sample code shortly.